# Solution check request for an exercise in Arbib and Manes's showing the existence of $\textbf{equalizer}$ in the category of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, category-theory, proof-explanation

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be linear maps between vector spaces $X,Y$.  Using the following exercise (one in the block quote), show that $\text{eq}(f,g)$ exists, where $\text{eq}(f,g)$ denotes the equalizer of $f,g$.  There is also another question with the same wording for coequalizer of $(f,g)$, but I will make a separate [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674255/an-exercise-in-arbib-and-maness-showing-the-existence-of-coequalizer-in-the-cat) for it.

> Let $X$ be a vector space.  If $A$ is a subset of $X$, show that there is at most one vector space structure on $A$ such that the inclusion map $i:A\rightarrow X$ is linear, and that this occurs iff $A$ is a subspace of $X$.  If $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X,$ show that there is at most one vector space structure on $X/E$ such that $\eta_E:X\rightarrow X/E$ is linear and that this occurs iff $[0]$ is a subspace of $X$ (in which case, $E=\{(x,x')\mid x-x'\in [0]\})$.)

$\textbf{Exercise question:}$  Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be linear.  Using exercise 3, (exercise in the quoted block text above) show that $\text{eq}(f,g)$ and $\text{coeq}(f,g)$ in $\textbf{Vect}.$

Can I let the set $K$ to be $K=\text{ker}(f-g),$ where $\text{ker}(f-g)=\{a\in X\mid (f-g)(a)=0\}=\{a\in X\mid f(a)=g(a)\}=\text{ker}(f).$  We define $h=eq(f-g,0):\text{ker}(f-g)\rightarrow X$ where $K\subset X$. If so,then here is my attempt at a proof.

Theorem:  $\textbf{Vect}$ has equalizers.

Proof:  Suppose $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are linear maps in the category of $\textbf{Vect},$ (category of vector space) and let $K=\text{ker}(f-g),$ where $\text{ker}(f-g)=\{a\in X\mid (f-g)(a)=0\}=\{a\in X\mid f(a)=g(a)\}.$ We define the embedding map $h:K\rightarrow X$ and  since $K\subset X,$ $h(K)\subset X$ then $f\circ h =g\circ h$.   Hence the map $h$ is a equalizer of the pair of maps $f,g$. Suppose there exists another map $\psi: D\rightarrow X$ in $\textbf{Vect}$ such that $f\circ \psi=g\circ \psi.$  The map $\psi$ being linear, $(f-g)(\psi)=0$, and $\psi\in K,$ along with the definition of $K$, $\psi(D)\subset K,$ hence $\text{im}(\psi)\subset K$.  There exists a unique map $\psi':D\rightarrow K$ in $\textbf{Vect},$ where $\psi=h\circ \psi'.$  Indeed, if $h\circ \psi''=\psi,$ where $\psi'':D\rightarrow K$ is in $\textbf{Vect};$ then $\psi=h\circ \psi'=h\circ \psi''.$  $h$ being injective, implies that $\psi'=\psi''$, which shows uniqueness.  Thus $h$ is the equalizer of the pair of maps $(f,g)$ and so $\textbf{Vect},$ has equalizers.

The above proof is adapted from "Categorical properties of locally $m-$convex algebras" by D Rosa, which appeared in: Topological vector Spaces, algebra and Related Area, by A Lau, I Tweddle.

In it, the two authors defined $L$ as the category of locally $m-$convex algebras.  Here is the reproduced proof.

> Theorem:  $L$ has equalizers.
>
> Proof: Given $\phi_1,\phi_2:A\rightarrow B$ in $L$, let $C=\{a\in A\mid \phi_1(a)=\phi_2(a)\}$ with the relative topology.  Clearly the natural embedding $i_C:C\rightarrow A$ is in $L$ and $\phi_1\circ i_C=\phi_2\circ i_C.$  Suppose there exists $\psi:D\rightarrow A$ in $L$ such that $\phi_1\circ \psi=\phi_2\circ \psi.$  By the definition of $C,$ it follows that $\psi(D)\subset C.$ So there exists a unique $\psi':D\rightarrow C$ in $L,$ namely the [corestriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corestriction) of $\psi,$ such that $\psi=i_C\circ \psi'.$ Thus $i_C$ is the equalizer of the pair $(\phi_1, \phi_2),$ and so $L$ has equalizers.

I have two quick questions:

(1) Is my attempt proof correct

(2) In Lau and Tweddle's proof above they did not define what $\psi'$ suppose to be, they did justify its existence in $L$ by stating that $\psi$ factors through $i_C$ because of the corestriction of $\psi$.

However can I let $\psi'=h^{-1}\circ \psi,$ where $h^{-1}$ is the inverse image of $h,$ meaning $h^{-1}(X)=K,$ and $(h\circ h^{-1})(X)=h(h^{-1}(X))=h(K).$  Also $\psi(D)\subset X,$ then $h\circ (h^{-1}\circ \psi)=(h\circ h^{-1})\circ \psi={id}_X \circ \psi=\psi.$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Your attempted proof is essentially correct but there are some notational errors, and some things I'd like to point out. Based on our previous interactions I think they are worth mentioning, but forgive me if it feels pedantic.

> "... and since $K\subset X$, $h(K)\subset X$ then $f\circ h=g\circ h$

That sentence looks like it is trying to convey: "$f\circ h=g\circ h$ folllows from the fact $h(K)\subset X$" which is definitely not true. Rather, $f\circ h=g\circ h$ is true simply by definition of $K$: for $a\in K$, $f(h(a))=f(a)=g(a)=g(h(a))$ by definition. That is why $fh=gh$.

> "The map $\psi$ being linear, $(f-g)\psi=0$"

Well, actually $(f-g)\psi$ would still be true even if $\psi$ wasn't linear.

When you say "$\psi\in K$", that doesn't make sense. Did you mean, for all $a\in D$, $\psi(a)\in K$? One last thing: you should also make sure you know why a linear map $\psi':D\to K$ *exists* (you got the uniqueness right) which is not something addressed in your proof.

$(2)$:

> "They did not define what $\psi'$ is supposed to be"

Neither did you! But $\psi'$ is defined exactly the same by both you and the authors of that text. $\psi':D\to C$ simply takes $d\mapsto\psi(d)$: since $\phi_1(\psi(d))=\phi_2(\psi(d))$ is true, $\psi(d)$ can be viewed as an element of $C$. This is indeed "corestriction".

> "However can I let $\psi'=h^{-1}\circ\psi$"

Yes and no... $h^{-1}$ doesn't necessarily exist as a function $X\to C$ and when you say "**meaning** $h^{-1}(X)=K$" etc. that's just not right: $h^{-1}(X)=K$ is true, but it doesn't exactly define what $h^{-1}$ is. $h^{-1}\circ\psi$ does make some sense, but only because $\psi(D)\subseteq C$, and once you've realised that, you've realised there's no need to talk about "$h^{-1}$".

Comment: thank you for commenting.  As usual, I am really amazed at your ability to figure out things in category theory.  I am not sure if it is a maturity thing or something else for me.

Comment: @Seth Getting to grips with the fundamentals of category theory does require a decent amount of the so-called "mathematical maturity". I suppose that's one of the main reasons category theory usually isn't taught until quite late (if at all) in an undergraduate course. For me, I find it's important to balance "going with the flow" with: being *really* sure that you know what all the statements mean before proceeding

Comment: I spoke to a friend about this post, and it got me thinking, I am not sure why using the "corestriction of $\psi$ is enough for the author to justify the existence for $\psi'.$  I mean I don't understand what the motivation or the logic for it.  As for the issue for the inverse image of $h^{-1}$, can I do the following:  given $h:K\rightarrow X$, let the $\textbf{fibre}$ of an element $x\in X$ under the map $h$ is the set  $h^{-1}(x)=\{k\in K\mid h(k)=x\}$, and since $\psi(d)\in X,$ then $\psi'=h^{-1}(\{\psi(d)\}).$  I think I was having trouble with the issue of whether I should use...

Comment: ...use inverse image of $h$ or the notion of fibre of a a map have to do with whether I should go down to the level of elements or stick to the level of morphism.  Also, when we are talking about the fibre of a map, are we still sticking to the level of morphism, or going down to the level of elements.  Last thing is, I assume or hope that the author assume that both $\psi, \psi'$ are both linear, since there might be complications of the mathematical kind if they are not.  I mean the proof is really short and feel almost terse.

Comment: @Seth In both cases, $\psi$ is linear if and only if $\psi'$ is linear. $\psi'$ is essentially the same thing as $\psi$ just with a restricted codomain. It's like the difference between considering $x\mapsto x^2$ as a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ or as a function $\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$. Now, $h^{-1}$ - the preimage - is usually defined through fibres. Notice that assignment of fibres is **not** a function, though, unless $h$ is invertible (which it technically isn't). So *a priori*, $h^{-1}\psi$ makes no sense as a function $D\to C$. $\psi$ is probably linear by definition of the category $L$

Comment: Terse proofs are a problem in general, but I wouldn't say this one is terse. It's short because, well, it's kinda easy... if you've studied any algebra you'll have already seen essentially the same proof carried out for groups and rings. Saying "*using* the corestriction" makes it sound like a complicated technical trick, but they justify the existence of $\psi'$ in an extremely easy way: since $\psi(d)\in C$ for any $d\in D$, we can think of a map $D\ni d\mapsto\psi(d)\in C$; call it $\psi'$. The corestriction is just a way to formally describe what they have done.

Comment: if it is not too much trouble, can I ask if you can read over the proof for [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674255/an-exercise-in-arbib-and-maness-showing-the-existence-of-coequalizer-in-the-cat).  Since it is about coequalizer and it is troublesome in category theory whenever there is a "co-" prefix to anything.  I want to know if I imitated the way proofs for coequalizer for abelian groups is done correctly for the case of vector spaces.  thank you.  oh yeah, I will take your word for it about having seen same proofs in case of grps, rngs, etc.

Comment: one other minor thing, isn't it better just to call it restricted codomain instead of "corestriction"?.  I mean, this is like the definition of cokernel versus kernel.

Comment: @Seth I had never heard of "corestriction" until this point, but I see no reason why not to call it that. It reminds you that you're technically creating a different map, and it's a little more easy to say than "the map obtained by restricting the codomain"