# Solution check request for an exercise in Arbib and Manes's showing the existence of $\textbf{coequalizer}$ in category $\textbf{Vect}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, category-theory

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be linear.  Using the following exercise (one in the block quote), show that $\text{coeq}(f,g)$ exists, where $\text{coeq}(f,g)$ denotes the coequalizer of $(f,g)$. I also posted the same question, but for showing that [equalizer in $\textbf{Vect}$ exists.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673761/an-exercise-in-arbib-and-maness-showing-the-existence-of-equalizer-in-the-categ)

> Let $X$ be a vector space.  If $A$ is a subset of $X$, show that there is at most one vector space structure on $A$ such that the inclusion map $i:A\rightarrow X$ is linear, and that this occurs iff $A$ is a subspace of $X$.  If $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X,$ show that there is at most one vector space structure on $X/E$ such that $\eta_E:X\rightarrow X/E$ is linear and that this occurs iff $[0]$ is a subspace of $X$ (in which case, $E=\{(x,x')\mid x-x'\in [0]\})$.)

$\textbf{Exercise question:}$  Let $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ be linear.  Using exercise 3, (exercise in the quoted block text above) show that $\text{eq}(f,g)$ and $\text{coeq}(f,g)$ in $\textbf{Vect}.$

Let the vector subspace $F=\text{Im}((f-g)(X))$ be defined as $\text{Im}((f-g)(X))=\{f(x)-g(x)\mid x\in X\},$ where $f,g:X\rightarrow Y.$  We also define $h=\text{coeq}(f-g,0):Y\rightarrow Y/F=Y/{\text{coeq}(f,g)}.$ If so,then here is my attempt at a proof.

Theorem:  $\textbf{Vect}$ has coequalizers

Proof:  Suppose $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are linear maps in the category of $\textbf{Vect}$.  Let $F$ be the subspace $F=\text{Im}((f-g)(X))=\{f(x)-g(x)\mid x\in X\},$ and let $E$ be the equivalence relation generated by $F$ where $E=\{(y,y')\mid [y]_F=[y']_F\in Y/F\}=\{(y,y')\mid [y]_F-[y']_F=[0]_F\in Y/F\}.$  Then the canonical quotient map $w:Y\rightarrow Y/F$ defined as $w(y)=[y]_F,$ is in $\textbf{Vect}$ and $w\circ f=w\circ g.$   Suppose there exists another linear map $\psi:Y\rightarrow D$ defined as $\psi(y)=d,$ in $\textbf{Vect}$ such that $\psi\circ f=\psi\circ g.$  Since $\psi$ is linear, and $w\circ f-w\circ g=w\circ(f-g)=0,$ then $(f-g)\in \text{ker}(w),$ $F\subset \text{ker}(w),$ and $E\subset \text{ker}(w).$ We assume that $\psi$ is compatible with $F,$ meaning for all $x, x'\in Y,$ $xFx'\Longrightarrow \psi(x)=\psi'(x').$ So let $A'=[y]_F=Y/F,$ and let $w'=\{(A',d)\in Y/F\times D\mid \exists y\in A' (\psi(y)=d)\}$  We need to show the existence of $w':Y/F\rightarrow D$ in $\textbf{Vect}.$  So suppose $A'\in Y/F.$  Let $y\in A'$ such that $A'=[y]_F.$  Let $\psi(y)=d.$  Since $y\in [y]_F=A'$ and $\psi(y)=d,$ we have $(A',d)\in w'.$  For showing $d$ being unique, suppose $(A',d')\in w'.$  Then we can let $y'\in A'$ such that $\psi(y')=d'.$  Since $y'\in A'=[y]_F,$ $yFy',$ and since $\psi$ is compatible with $F,$ $d'=\psi(y)=\psi(y')=d,$ which implies $w'(w(y))=w'([y]_F)=\psi(y).$
To show that $w'$ is unique, suppose that $w'':Y/F\to D$  and for all $y\in A', w''(w(y))=w''([y]_F)=\psi(y).$  Suppose $A'\in Y/F,$ then we can pick some $y\in A'$ where $A'=[y]_F.$  Therefore $w''(A')=w''(w(y))=w''([y]_F)=\psi(y)=w'([y]_F)=w'(w(y))=w'(A').$  Since $A'$ was arbitrary, we have $w''=w',$ and we have shown that $w'(w(y))=w'([y]_F)=\psi(y).$ Then $w'\circ w=\psi.$ Thus $w$ is the coequalizer of the pair of linear maps $(f,g)$ and so $\textbf{Vect}$ has coequalizers.

The above proof is adapted from how coequalizer are determined in the case of abelian groups, and also from a theorem in an article titled: "Categorical properties of locally $m-$convex algebras" by D Rosa, which appeared in the text: Topological vector Spaces, algebra and Related Area, by A Lau, I Tweddle.

In that article, the two authors defined $L$ as the category of locally $m-$convex algebras.  Here is the reproduced proof.

> Theorem:  $L$ has coequalizers.
>
> Proof: Given $\psi_1, \psi_2:A\rightarrow B$ in $\textbf{L},$ let $I$ be the closure of the ideal generated by $\{\psi_1(a)-\psi_2(a):a\in A\}.$  Then the canonical quotient map $Q:B\rightarrow B/I$ is in $\textbf{L}$ and $Q\circ \psi_1=Q\circ \psi_2.$  Suppose there exists $\psi:B\rightarrow D$ in $\textbf{L},$ such that $\psi\circ \phi_1=\psi\circ \phi_2.$  Since $\psi$ is continuous it follows that $I\subset \text{ker}(\psi).$  Hence there exists a unique $\psi':B/I\rightarrow D$ in $\textbf{L},$ such that $\psi'\circ Q=\psi.$  Thus $Q$ is the coequalizer of the pair $(f,g)$ and in $\textbf{L},$ has coequalizers.

Also for constructing the coequalizer in the category of $\textbf{Grp}$ is a solution to the following question (from Harold Simmons' category theory text):

> Consider a parallel pair of morphisms $f,g:A\to B$ between groups (written multiplicatively)
> Let
> $$F=\{f(a)g(a)^{-1}\mid a\in A\}$$
>
> and let $K$ be the normal subgroup generated by $F.$ Show that the canonical quotient $B\to B/K$ is the coequalizer of $f$ and $g$ in $\textbf{Grp}$
>
> Proof:  Given $f,g:A\to B\xrightarrow{k}B/K$
>
> where $K$ is the canonical quotient.  For each $a\in A$ we have
>
> $$k(f(a)g(a)^{-1})=k(1)=1$$
>
> which leads to $$k(f(a))=k(g(a))$$
>
> and hence $k$ does make equal $f$ and $g$.  We show that $k$ is the coequalizer of $f$ and $g$.
>
> Consider the group morphism $$B\xrightarrow{h}X$$
>
> which does make equal $f$ and $g$.  For each $a\in A$ we have $$h(f(a))=h(g(a))$$
>
> so that $$h(f(a)g(a)^{-1})=h(1)=1$$
>
> and hence $$f(a)g(a)^{-1}\in {ker}(h)$$
>
> to show $$F\subset {ker}(h)$$
>
> and hence $$K\subset {ker}(h)$$
>
> by the construction of $K.$  There is a unique morphism $m$ for which $h=m\circ k$

I have quick question:

Is my proof correct? In particular, I used the idea of ideal of $I$ being the equivalence relation generated by the direct image of $f-g$.  I hope it matches with the equivalence relation $E$ in the quoted exercise.  Also, I know $Y/F$ has to do with the cokernel of $w$, but I did not mentioned that.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:  I found out there was some typos and made the necessary corrections, and also, I was able to figure out how to adapt or imitate the idea/technique from the case of abelian groups.

Answer (score 2):

Like with the other post the proof is essentially right but has some confusions and gaps.

As noted by another user in another post of yours, the often-quoted "exercise $3$" is wrong ("has a linear structure iff. $[0]$ is a subspace..."). All that you need to care about is that, given any subspace $K$ of $U$, there is a quotient $U/K$.

---

> "Since $\psi$ is linear, and $w\circ f-w\circ g=w\circ(f-g)=0$, then $(f−g)\in\ker(w),\,F\subset\ker(w)$ and $E\subset\ker(w)$.

This is mostly true, but has absolutely nothing to do with $\psi$. $F=\ker w$ *exactly*, not just $F\subset\ker w$, and $E\subset\ker w$ is wrong. $E$ is a subset of $Y\times Y$ and $\ker w$ is a subset of $Y$.

Then your "hence there exists a unique $w'$..." is coming from nowhere. You have not actually made any deductions from the fact $\psi f=\psi g$.

By copying the proof from the other text you seem to have lost sight of what's going on. I strongly recommend thinking through each sentence of the other text for yourself so you know exactly why it is true. Maybe remind yourself of the "universal property of the quotient map" for set-based categories: that's basically what you're trying to prove here. You know $\psi f=\psi g$, now you need to tell the reader exactly why that implies there is a (unique) linear map $\psi':Y/F\to D$ satisfying $\psi'\circ w=\psi$. You haven't done that yet (and that is arguably the main point of the proof).

Some thoughts for you:

How should we define $\psi'([y])$ for some equivalence class $[y]\in Y/F$? You'd like to set it equal to $\psi'([y]):=\psi(y)$ (why do we want that?) but there's a problem with *well-definedness*: what if $[y]=[y']$, can we then be sure that $\psi(y')=:\psi'([y'])=\psi'([y])=\psi(y)$?

Comment: I have been feeling under the weather again for the last few days.  Sorry for my late reply.  I have fixed the proof and added the bit about the reference solution for coequalizers for category of groups to my answer..  The main thing I want to ask you is where I stated "Let $F$ be the subspace $F=\text{Im}((f-g)(X))=\{f(x)-g(x)\mid x\in X\},$ and let $E$ be the equivalence relation generated by $F$ where $E=\{(y,y')\mid [y]=[y']\in Y/F\}=\{(y,y')\mid [y]-[y']=[0]\in Y/F\}.$ ", is that phrase correctly.  Also did I show the relationship $w'\circ w=\psi$ correctly?

Comment: @Seth “Is that phrase correctly”: yes, as a clause that makes sense and the description of $E$ is correct. Remember we actually define (on the level of sets) $Y/F:=Y/E$ where $E=\{(y,y’):y-y’\in F\}$ so although it is correct that $E=\{(y,y’):[y]=[y’]\in Y/F\}$, it strikes me as a little odd to say it like that since $E$ is defined first and $Y/F$ is defined second.

Comment: You didn’t show $\psi’\circ w=\psi$ correctly because you didn’t actually show anything at all concerning $\psi’$. You just said: “there exists a unique (linear) $\psi’$ with $\psi’\circ w=\psi$” and really it is the most important part of the proof, to show $\psi’$ exists. See my further commentary in the later half of the post for some hints to help you do that part. Also, I am sorry to hear you have been feeling under the weather recently.

Comment: @Seth No worries. Yes, that would be a way to justify $w’\circ w=\psi$, but… *you haven’t shown such a $w’$ exists that has the desired properties*. This is like the coproduct exercise from another post (“show that a section $s:A\to A_j$ exists…”); you **must** justify the existence of such $w’$ (which makes more sense to be called $\psi’$) and that is the whole crux of the proof. At the moment, $w’$ may as well be a meaningless symbol: you might be writing $\text{banana}\circ w=\psi$: until you *define* $w’$ and show it exists, we may as well be talking nonsense.

Comment: So, maybe following the hints in my answer, explain why $w’$ exists. Take inspiration from the analogous proofs for Set, if you wish. Note that the proof you reference (about the category $L$) doesn’t go into detail about why $\psi’$ should exist because it treats that as a well-known fact. However, for you, it is your job to understand and come up with this ‘well-known’ fact yourself; I am not sure that you have appreciated that fact just yet

Comment: is showing existence of $w$ similar to how is done is the first isomorphism theorems for rings and groups, where I have to show $w$ to be  well-defined, one to one, onto and linear?  I am not sure if I am require to show one to one and onto.  I will fix the proof tomorrow morning and I will message you here tomorrow.  Also, I am doing a couple more exercises on pullback, kernel and pushout, Cokernel for vector spaces.  When I am done, can I ask you to look over them if I did them correctly.  thanks.

Comment: @Seth *not* existence of $w$: you hopefully already know how that works. You need to show existence (and uniqueness) of $w’$ (or $\psi’$, as I would rather say) with $w’w=\psi$. It’s not going to be similar to the first isomorphism theorem, it’s just about demonstrating the universal property of quotients of vector spaces, very similar to the proof for Set.

Comment: I finally fixed the post according to your suggestion. Actually, I think i did a bit more in terms of being more pedantic.  Can you see if it is okay now.  Also, I posted about [pullback](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747289/showing-that-the-kernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pullback-diagram) and [pushout](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747287/showing-that-the-cokernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pushout-diagram).  Can you take a look to see if they are okay if you have a moment.  Thank you.

Comment: @Seth your updated proof is hard to follow notationally etc. and the first few paragraphs of my answer still apply. It's very rare to actually define a function via a relation like that, writing $w'=\{(A,d):\cdots\}$ confused me. However, it does look ok now

Comment: If you have a moment, can I ask you about the following two posts:  [kernel-pullback](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747289/showing-that-the-kernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pullback-diagram/4747395?noredirect=1#comment10073978_4747395)
and
[cokernel-pushout](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747287/showing-that-the-cokernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pushout-diagram), I tried to imitate Roman's solution.  I am not sure what Nico is trying to tell me.  I am not critizing him...

Comment: I think from his response, I replied back explaining I am a bit confused over what I have to do for the question, specifically, do i need to show existence of a mapping for showing universal mapping property for both pullback and pushout.  thanks

Comment: Also when are you on that discord server.  I want to go check it out this weekend.  last time I said I was going to do it, I felt under the weather.  Hopefully I can come by and check it out since I have never been on a discord server before.