# Showing that the CoKernel in $\textbf{Vect}$ is given by a pushout diagram

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, pullback

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes,  "Advanced Modern Algebra" 2nd edition by Rotman, and
"Representation theory of the Virasoro Algebra" by Iohara and Koga.

$\color{green}{Background}$

From Iohara and Koga's Representation theory of the Virasoro Algebra.

$\textbf{(1):}$  A pair $(C,p)$ is called the $\textit{cokernel}$ of $f$ if it satisfies

i.  $p\circ f=0$ and
ii. for any morphism such that $q\circ f=0$ there exists a unique morphism $r$ such that $q=r\circ p.$

In such case, the object $C$ is often denoted by $\text{Coker }f$

From Rotman's Advanced Abstract Algebra 2nd edition.

$\textbf{(2)}$  Definition:  Given two morphisms $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:A\rightarrow C$ in a category $\textbf{C},$ a $\textbf{solution}$ is an ordered triple $(D,\alpha,\beta)$ making the left-hand diagram commute. A $\textbf{pushout}$ (or $\textit{fibered sum}$ is a solution $(D,\alpha,\beta)$ that is "best" in the following sense:  for every solution $(X,\alpha',\beta'),$ there exists a unique morphism $\theta:D\rightarrow X$ making the right-hand diagram commute.

[image]

Showing that cokernel is a pullback in the case of $_R\textbf{Mod}.$

[image]

Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism in $_R\textbf{Mod},$ then the pullback of the first diagram below is $({coker}f,\pi,0),$ where $\pi:B\rightarrow {coker}f$ is the natural map, and ${coker}f=B/\text{im}f.$

$\textbf{(3)}$  $\textbf{Proposition:}$  Every coequalizer is an epimorphism.

Proof:  If $h=\text{coeq}(p_1,p_2)$ and $k_1\circ h=k_2\circ h,$ then $$(k_1\circ k_2)\circ p_1=k_1\circ(h\circ P_2)=k_1\circ(h\circ p_2)=(k_1\circ h)\circ p_2$$ and so there is a unique morphism $\psi$ such that $k_1\circ h=\psi\circ h.$  Thus $k_1=\psi=k_2.$

$\textbf{(4) Proposition:}$ In the category $\textbf{Vect}$

$\textbf{(i)}$ $f$ is an epimorphism $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is onto $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is a coequalizer

$\textbf{(ii)}$ $f$ is a monomorphism  $\quad\text{iff}\quad$  $f$ is one-to-one $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is an equalizer

$\textbf{(5)}$ $\textit{A coequalizer is an epimorphism.}$

Proof:  If $f:A\to B$ $\textit{is an epimorphism, f is onto.}$  Let $E$ be the equivalence relation $\{(b,b')\mid b-b'\in f(A)\}$ on $B.$  Following a standard if sloppy convention, we write the quotient set as $B/f(A)$ rather than $B/E.  B/E$ is easily checked to be a vector space with operations $[b]+[b']=[b+b'], \lambda\cdot[b]=[\lambda\cdot b].$

Define the two linear maps $$t:B\to B/f(A):b\mapsto [b]$$
$$u:B\to B/f(A):b\to [0].$$  Then $t\circ f$ and $u\circ f$ are both zero maps (since $[f(a)]=[0]$ for all $a$ in $A$) and so $t=u$ because $f$ is an epimorphism.  Thus for all $b\in B, [b]=[0],b\in f(A),$ and $f$ is onto.

$\color{Blue}{Exercise:}$

[image]

Show that the the pushout diagram describes the $\textbf{cokernel}$ of $f$ is the construction $\eta:B\rightarrow B/f(A).$ used in the proof of $\textbf{(2)}$

$\color{Red}{Solution:}$

Solution:  We relabel the above diagram as:

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y\\
\small {}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {\eta}  &  \\
0 & \xrightarrow{} & C
\end{array}$

and we note that $C=\text{Coker}(f)=Y/f(X).$  Also, we let $X=A$ and $B=Y,$ and the linear map $\eta:B\to B/f(A)$ to be relabel as $\eta:Y\to Y/f(X)$ in $\textbf{(5)}.$  So suppose $\eta\cdot f=0.$ Let $C'=\text{Coker}(f)$ so that $\eta':Y\to C'$ is another linear map where $\eta'\cdot f=0,$ and $\eta\cdot f=\eta'\cdot f=0.$  Let $\theta:C\to C'$ be a linear map such that $(\theta\cdot \eta)(b)=\theta(\eta(b))=\theta([b])=\eta'(b)=[b],$ for all $b\in Y.$  If $\theta':C\to C'$ is another linear map where $\theta'\cdot \eta=\theta'\cdot \eta.$  Since $\eta$ is an onto map, hence by $\textbf{(4)(i)},$ $\eta$ is an epimorphism.  Therefore $\theta=\theta'$ which shows that $\theta$ is unique.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to know if I did the exercise correctly.  I tried to imitate how Rotman did the similar exercise for modules. I have also attached screenshots of the diagrams from Rotman's text to make his proof easier to follow. I gave more details on showing the existence of $\theta:C\to C'.$  I am not sure why Rotman did not included it.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dual question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747289/showing-that-the-kernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pullback-diagram