# Showing that the Kernel in $\textbf{Vect}$ is given by a pullback diagram

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, pullback

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes,  "Advanced Modern Algebra" 2nd edition by Rotman, and
"Representation theory of the Virasoro Algebra" by Iohara and Koga.

$\color{green}{Background}$

From Iohara and Koga's Representation theory of the Virasoro Algebra.

$\textbf{(1):}$  A pair $(K,i)$ is called the $\textit{kernel}$ of $f$ if it satisfies

i.  $f\circ i=0$ and

ii.  for any morphism such that $f\circ j=0$ there exists a unique morphism $k$ such that $j=i\circ k.$

In such case, the object $K$ is often denoted by $\text{ker }f$

From Rotman's Advanced Abstract Algebra 2nd edition.

From Rotman's Advanced Abstract Algebra 2nd edition.

$\textbf{(2):}$ Definition:  Given two morphisms $f:B\rightarrow A$ and $g:C\rightarrow A$ in a category $\textbf{C},$ a $\textbf{solution}$ is an ordered triple $(D,\alpha,\beta)$ making the left-hand diagram commute. A $\textbf{pullback}$ (or $\textit{fibered product}$ is a solution $(D,\alpha,\beta)$ that is "best" in the following sense:  for every solution $(X,\alpha',\beta'),$ there exists a unique morphism $\theta:X\rightarrow D$ making the right-hand diagram below commute.

[image]

Showing that kernel is a pullback in the case of $_R\textbf{Mod}.$

[image]

Suppose $f:B\rightarrow A$ is a homomorphism in $_R\textbf{Mod},$ then the pullback of the first diagram below is $({ker}f,0,i),$ where $i:{ker}f\rightarrow B$ is the inclusion. Let $i':X\rightarrow B$ be a map with $f\circ i'=0;$ then $(f\circ i')(x)=0$ for all $x\in X,$ and so $i'(x)\in {ker}f.$  If we define $\theta:X\rightarrow {ker}f$ to be the map obtained from $i'$ by changing its target, then the diagram commutes:  $i\circ \theta =i'.$  To prove uniqueness of the map $\theta,$ suppose that $\theta':X\rightarrow {ker}f$ satisfies $i\circ\theta'=i'.$  Since $i$ is the inclusion, $\theta'(x)=i'(x)=\theta(x)$ for all $x\in X,$ and so $\theta'=\theta.$  Thus, $({ker}f,0,i)$ is a pullback.

From Arbib and Manes "Categorical Imperative"

$\textbf{(3) Proposition:}$ In the category $\textbf{Vect}$

$\textbf{(i)}$ $f$ is an epimorphism $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is onto $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is a coequalizer

$\textbf{(ii)}$ $f$ is a monomorphism  $\quad\text{iff}\quad$  $f$ is one-to-one $\quad\text{iff}\quad$ $f$ is an equalizer

$\textbf{(4):}$  Definition:  Let $\textbf{K}$ be a category with zero object $0.$  Then the $\textbf{kernel}$ $u:K\to A$ of $f:A\to B$ is given by the pullback diagram

[image]

$\color{Blue}{Exercise:}$  Let $f:X\to Y$ be a linear map in $\textbf{Vect}.$  Prove that the kernel of $f$ as in $(2)$ is the usual construction of the subspace $\{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\}.$

$\color{Red}{Solution:}$

Proof:  We relabel the diagram in $\textbf{(2)}$ as follow:

$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} K & \xrightarrow{} & 0\\
\small {u}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {}  &  \\
X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y 
\end{array}$

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a linear map between vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ in $\textbf{Vect}.$ Let $K=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\},$ and  $u:K\to X$ be a linear map such that $f\cdot u=0$, hence  $u\in \text{ker}(f).$  Let $K'=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\}$ and $u':K'\to X$ be another linear map such that $f\cdot u'=0,$ and so $f\cdot u=f\cdot u'=0.$ If $\theta:K'\to K$ is a linear map such that $u\cdot \theta=u'.$ Then $(u\cdot \theta)(x)=u(\theta(x))=u'(x),$ for all $x\in X,$ which implies $\theta(x)=x.$   If $\theta'$ is also another linear map such that $u\cdot \theta'=u',$ then $u\cdot \theta=u\cdot \theta'=u'.$  But the map $u:K\to X$ is an inclusion map, hence it is one-to-one.  So by $\textbf{(3)(ii)},$ $u$ is a monomorphism, and so $\theta=\theta',$  which shows that $\theta$ is unique.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to know if I did the exercise correctly.  I tried to imitate how Rotman did the similar exercise for modules. I have also attached screenshots of the diagrams from Rotman's text to make his proof easier to follow. I gave more details on showing the existence of $\theta:K'\to K.$  I am not sure why Rotman did not included it.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dual question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747287/showing-that-the-cokernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pushout-diagram

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang thank you for posting that for me.  I did not know I can reference my other question like the way you did.

Answer (score 1):

I have some trouble following your solution. What the exercise asks you to do is to start with $K = \{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\}$ and the morphism $u: K\to X$ (which is just the inclusion $u(x) = x$) and to show that the diagram which you have drawn satsifies the correct universal property. This means your solution can not start with "let $u:K\to X$ be a map" because the map $u$ is already given and fixed.

What you need to show is the following: Given any other vector space $W$ and any two maps $g:W\to X$ and $h:W\to 0$ such that $f\circ g = 0\circ h$, there is a unique map $\theta:W\to K$ such that $u\circ \theta =g$ and $0\circ \theta = h$. This is less complicated in diagram form, so I have made a picture for you:

[image]

I hope this helps, universal properties can be confusing at first. Good luck and write a comment if you stay stuck! :)

Comment: can we chat about this.  I know you have in the past wrote answers to my posts and some of them were very detailed.  I don't want to get in trouble with the mods if we get into too much back and forth with the comments.  Also, the issues I am having with the exercise in this post, I also have with the dual post about cokernel and pushout diagram.

Comment: @Seth sure! i don't know how exactly chatting works on this website, but if it doesn't than we can also use some other platform :) (some mods  here are very unfriendly for no good reason, imo)

Comment: you said in your profile about people wanting to talk category theory with you can message you.  I don't know how to do that on this platform.

Comment: I have created a chat room category theory.  I invited you and FShrike.  Not sure if either of you can see it.  I am in north America EST -5:00.  I think both you and FShrike are slightly ahead of me in terms of time.

Comment: if you like, do you have a webpage where I can email and ask you question about this post.  i try to find you online but I don't know which one is you since there are a few people with your name sake in Berlin who also is into mathematics.

Comment: @Seth I don't have a web page, but I have added an E Mail to my profile. If you send me a mail then I can share more contact information with you, and we can also talk if you like :) I think I am also in the Chat room now 

Comment: I am on here.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147688/category-theory If you are in a different chatroom, let me know.  I will try to move over.

Comment: I actually found you.  You are in Martin's chat room.  :)  I will send you an email.  It will have my name on it and the subject heading contains reference to math stackexchange in a few hours. I appreciate you coming on.   I just need to get a few hours of sleep.  Again, thank you so much for your contact info.

Comment: sorry for replying back here so late.  I hope you are having a good week.  I emailed you a few days ago. I am not sure if you received it.  it had math stackexchange in the subject heading....

Comment: also for my solution above, for showing the universal mapping property, do I need to show existence.  The reasoning ask is I think I am a bit confused over the wording of the question now that I think about it.  Does the question ask the reader to rewrite the definition of kernel using the definition of Pullback.  Or is it asking the reader to show that kernel for vector space satisfies the universal mapping property by showing existence of a unique map?  I guess my question apply to the dual post for this question too.

Comment: @Seth I would say that the text generalises the definition of a kernel to an arbitrary abelian category, and then asks you to check that the new definition agrees with the old one in the case when the abelian category is a category of modules over a ring. This means that you have to check that a kernel in the old sense does indeed fit into a pullback diagram. Does that make sense?

Comment: I edited my post. First, sorry for the confusing notations.  I should have included the attached diagram from Rotman's text.  My understanding of your explanation for what the question is asking me to show is that the definition off Kernel for linear maps between vector spaces satisfies the definition of the Pullback.  Similarly for this [cokernel-pushout](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747287/showing-that-the-cokernel-in-textbfvect-is-given-by-a-pushout-diagram) post.  I am not sure if my revision is more clear.  I think when you said i...

Comment: can't simply started with "let $:\to $ be a map," I was simply imitating how Rotman started with his proof. I tried looking up online on how question with pullback is done as I was not able to find any, I thought I would do something similar to be on the safe side.  Can I ask if you can check if my revision for this post and my other post are okay.  I am really uncertain about if I showed the universal mapping properly by showing existence for both posts.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Seth no, Rotman does not do the same thing as you. The sentence "Let $u$ be a map such that $fu=0$, then $u\in ker(f)$" does not work. Are you sure that you know exactly what you want to show? Being a pullback is a property of a square of arrows. The exercise asks you to show that some specific square is a pullback. How does that square look like?

Comment: @Seth you defined the correct square in your other question, but when you tried to show that it is a pushout you did the same mistake as in this question. You still seem to have some kind of misunderstanding, but I am not exactly sure what it is -.-

Comment: I just replied to your email.  Hm...when Rotman begins his proof with: "Suppose $f:B\rightarrow A$ is a homomorphism in $_R\textbf{Mod},$ then the pullback of the first diagram below is $({ker}f,0,i),$ where $i:{ker}f\rightarrow B$ is the inclusion."   Since the text I am using does't assume that I can use the definition that Rotman includes.  I am not sure how else I can begin the proof.  Also, did I show the universal mapping property for both posts correctly??

Comment: @Seth what is $u$ in your proof is $i$ in rotmans proof. Note that Rotman just defines $i$, it is the inclusion. Rotman then continues with let $i':X\to B$ be some other (!!) map such that $fi' = 0$ and continues. Note that $X$ is also a new abitrary test object. If you want to write your proof so that it looks like Rotman's then you have to start with "let $u':W\to X$ be some other map such that $fu' = 0$, and not change $u$, because $u$ is like $i$ in Rotman's proof already fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147870/discussion-between-nico-and-seth).

Comment: can I ask you with helping me with the other post on cokernel.  i am not sure if I need to do some quotienting process to find the necessary map for showing the universal mapping property like in the case of showing the existence of coequalizer for the category of a mathematical object.